# Sonar uses oracle as the database connection

Tags: sonarqube

How to configure the sonar.properties file to make the sonar connect to the oracle expression edition database? Could any one give me some examples? Btw, I have install both sonar and oracle EX locally on my 32-bit machine running windows xp. Thanks

Comment: Could I humbly suggest that you read the properties file? The Sonarsource guys have already done the work for you, providing examples of how to connect databases like MySQL, Oracle, Postgres...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sonar.properties file, you just have to comment out the lines related to Derby and uncomment the one related to Oracle, this is that simple.

For instance:

```
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sonar;create=true
...
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE
```

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully get the connection.